# NameError: name 'log10' is not defined in function called in script

Tags: python-3.x

Why `log10()` is failing to be recognized when called within a function definition in another script? I'm running Python3 in Anaconda (Jupyter and Spyder).

I've had success with `log10()` in Jupyter (oddly without even calling "import math"). I've had success with defining functions in a .py file and calling those functions within a separate script. I should be able to perform a simple log10.

I created a new function (in Spyder) and saved it in a file "test_log10.py":

```
def test_log10(input):
    import math
    return math.log10(input)
```

In a separate script (Jupyter notebook) I run :

```
import test_log10
test_log10.test_log10(10)
```

I get the following error:

> "NameError: name 'log10' is not defined"

What am I missing?

Comment: By the way, I've found numerous similarly titled enquiries (i.e. NameError: name X not defined).  It seems the majority of issues are calling of a function (or variable) before defining it.  I'm fairly certain this isn't the issue I'm having.  Equally I've read other questions and responses to them and none seem to apply to my problem.  So I've not just posted this without doing a fair bit of digging!

Comment: I've attempted some further debugging - I tried replacing                 return math.log10(input)                                                                      with                                                                                                             return -1                                                                                            Incredibly I still get the error.  I've saved the file after modiying it so can't fathom what's going on.

Comment: Something interesting and unexpected happened when I decided to restart the Jupyter kernel.  When I re-ran the problemmatic script the error didn't occur.  I was then able to recreate the error (by commenting out import math in the function definition), and re-create the error.  And again eliminate the error by restarting the kernel.  So it appears to be something to do with the function not being updated in the kernel (or memory) even though I have (1) saved the .py file containing the function; and (2) imported the function in the script before trying to call it.

Comment: I'm curious to know if anyone has any insight on why this has happened.  Is it expected?  Is it a bug?  Is there any other way to subvert this without having to resort to restarting the kernel?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add details instead of adding comments. As well, you need to add the full error message, and preferably make a [mre].

Answer (score -1):

Since I'm not using the environment of Jupyther and alike, I don't know how to correct it in these system, perhaps there is some configuration file over there,check the documentation.

But exactly on the issue, when this happens its because python has not "linked" well something at the import, so I suggest a workaround with the libs in the next way:

```
import numpy as np
import math
```

and when you are using functions from math, simply add the np. before, i.e.:

```
return math.log10(input)
```

to

```
return np.math.log10(input)
```

Exactly I don't know why the mismatch, but this worked for me.